# Using perl to split a line that may contain whitespace

Tags: regex, perl, split, whitespace

Okay, so I'm using perl to read in a file that contains some general configuration data. This data is organized into headers based on what they mean. An example follows:

```
[vars]

# This is how we define a variable!
$var = 10;
$str = "Hello thar!";


# This section contains flags which can be used to modify module behavior
# All modules read this file and if they understand any of the flags, use them
[flags] 
  Verbose =       true; # Notice the errant whitespace!

[path]
WinPath = default; # Keyword which loads the standard PATH as defined by the operating system. Append  with additonal values.
LinuxPath = default;
```

Goal: Using the first line as an example "$var = 10;", I'd like to use the split function in perl to create an array that contains the characters "$var" and "10" as elements. Using another line as an example:

```
    Verbose    =         true;
    # Should become [Verbose, true] aka no whitespace is present
```

This is needed because I will be outputting these values to a new file (which a different piece of C++ code will read) to instantiate dictionary objects. Just to give you a little taste of what it might look like (just making it up as I go along):

```
define new dictionary
name: [flags]
# Start defining keys => values
new key name: Verbose
new value val: 10 
# End dictionary
```

Oh, and here is the code I currently have along with what it is doing (incorrectly):

```
sub makeref($)
{
    my @line = (split (/=/)); # Produces ["Verbose", "    true"];
}
```

To answer one question, why I am not using Config::Simple, is that I originally did not know what my configuration file would look like, only what I wanted it to do. Making it up as I went along - at least what seemed sensible to me - and using perl to parse the file.

The problem is I have some C++ code that will load the information in the config file, but since parsing in C or C++ is :( I decided to use perl. It's also a good learning exercise for me since I am new to the language. So that's the thing, this perl code is not really apart of my application, it just makes it easier for the C++ code to read the information. And, it is more readable (both the config file, and the generated file). Thanks for the feedback, it really helped.

Comment: Don't use prototypes unless they are necessary. Even then, think thrice. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes *This is all very powerful, of course, and should be used only in moderation to make the world a better place.*

Comment: Please see FM's answer. You really shouldn't be writing your own file parser to do such a common and standard job -- use CPAN, and focus on your application logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're doing this parsing as a learning exercise, that's fine. However, [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) has several modules that will do a lot of the work for you.

```
use Config::Simple;
Config::Simple->import_from( 'some_config_file.txt', \my %conf );
```

Comment: Yeah, I've really got to ask why the OP is using what is very similar to a standard config file format, but not using the standard config file reader modules that are readily available and very well-tested.  (YAML is another good one to look at if Config::Simple doesn't quite match the desired format.)

Comment: 95% time this is what would be wanted. I've got some reasons (learning, not all of my code is in perl) that make it easier to do it differently.

Answer (score 3):

`split` splits on a regular expression, so you can simply put the whitespace around the `=` sign into its regex:

```
split (/\s*=\s*/, $line);
```

You obviously do not want to remove *all* whitespace, or such a line would be produced (whitespace missing in the string):

```
$str="Hellothere!";
```

I guess that only removing whitespace from the beginning and end of the line is sufficient:

```
$line =~ s/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/$1/;
```

A simpler alternative with two statements:

```
$line =~ s/^\s+//;
$line =~ s/\s+$//;
```

Comment: Please note the messed up syntax highlighting.

Comment: That's why I tend to use `s{...}{...}` when posting on SO.

Comment: `s/^\s+//` is slightly more efficient.

Comment: Yes, if there are zero whitespace characters, `s/^\s*//` replaces nothing with nothing--why bother?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you've got it.  Strip the whitespaces before splitting.

```
sub makeref($)
{
    s/\s+//g;
    my @line = (split(/=/)); # gets ["verbose", "true"]
}
```

Comment: Ahh its so obvious now. Thanks, I'm new to perl and its a really cool language.

Comment: Oddly, chomp does not chomp whitespaces!

Comment: you're right, I thought about it and the regex solution is better, go with that.

Comment: Please note the messed up syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Tommy Read `perldoc -f chomp` to find out what `chomp` does `chomp`.

Comment: Hope your parameters and values don't have spaces: `background color = dark red`

Answer (score 1):

This code does the trick (and is more efficient without reversing).

```
for (@line) {
    s/^\s+//;
    s/\s+$//;
}
```

Comment: you could add a 'g' to the end of the regex to get it to replace more than one extra whitespace appearance.  i.e. `s/^\s+//g;`

Comment: Please note the messed up syntax highlighting.

Comment: There are many modules that handle configuration sections, continuation lines, variables with multiple values etc etc on CPAN. Use one of them once you are done learning. I like `Config::Std`. @FM pointed out `Config::Simple`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have it all figured out, but I thought I'd add a little.  If you

```
sub makeref($)
{
   my @line = (split(/=/));
   foreach (@line)
   {
      s/^\s+//g;
      s/\s+$//g;
   }
}
```

then you will remove the whitespace before and after both the left and right side. That way something like:

```
 this is a parameter         =      all sorts of stuff here
```

will not have crazy spaces.

!!Warning: I probably don't know what I'm talking about!!